# How to force scipy to integrate using Adams?

Tags: python, numpy

I was using `scipy.integrate.odeint`, and ran into trouble when it switched to the `bdf` method (because the system appears stiff).  Unfortunately, `bdf` requires calculating a Jacobian.  My system has hundreds of thousands of equations, so this kills Python (segmentation fault!!)

I've got good reason to believe that adams would do just fine on this system.  So I'd like to force scipy to use it.  I don't think that's possible with `odeint`, so I'm trying to use `ode`.  I've written my own function that should take the same inputs as `odeint`.  It looks like something just isn't right with my code:

```
def my_odeint(dfunc, V0, times, args=()):
    r = integrate.ode(dfunc)
    r.set_integrator('vode', method='adams')
    r.set_initial_value(V0,times[0]).set_f_params(*args)
    V=[V0]
    for time in times[1:]:
        V.append(r.integrate(time))
    V = scipy.array(V)
    return V
```

When I test it I get an error:

```
def dx(X, t):
    x=X[0]
    y=X[1]
    return (-x, x+y)
X0 = [1,1]
times = scipy.linspace(0,2,10)
my_odeint(dx, X0, times)
> capi_return is NULL
> Call-back cb_f_in_dvode__user__routines failed.
```

Then

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cc286a9956a2> in <module>()
----> 1 my_odeint(dx, X0, times)

in my_odeint(dfunc, V0, times, args)
   1352     V=[V0]
   1353     for time in times[1:]:
-> 1354         V.append(r.integrate(time))

in integrate(self, t, step, relax)
    406             self._y, self.t = mth(self.f, self.jac or (lambda: None),
    407                                 self._y, self.t, t,
--> 408                                 self.f_params, self.jac_params)

 in run(self, f, jac, y0, t0, t1, f_params, jac_params)
    863         args = ((f, jac, y0, t0, t1) + tuple(self.call_args) +
    864                 (f_params, jac_params))
--> 865         y1, t, istate = self.runner(*args)

<ipython-input-4-1770d3974ec9> in dx(X, t)
      1 def dx(X, t):
----> 2     x=X[0]
      3     y=X[1]

> TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So my question is - how do I fix my code so that I have a function which takes identical input as `odeint` but uses `adams` and never switches to `bdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scipy.ode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) requires a right hand side in the form `f(t, y, *f_args)`, and [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) requires it in the form `f(y, t, *f_args)`.

So this will work:

```
def my_odeint(dfunc, V0, times, args=()):
    r = integrate.ode(lambda t, X: scipy.array(dfunc(X, t, *args)))
    r.set_integrator('vode', method='adams')
    r.set_initial_value(V0,times[0])
    V=[V0]
    for time in times[1:]:
        V.append(r.integrate(time))
    V = scipy.array(V)
    return V
```

Note that according to the documentation, vode implements Adams-Moulton, not Adams-Bashforth. That is, you still have an implicit method. If integration continues to fail, give the Dormand/Prince methods also implemented in `integrate.ode` a try.

Comment: So this looks like it fixes one error, but there still seems to be a problem.  My `dfunc` requires `7` arguments.  I've checked that `args` has length 5. However, I'm getting the error `in <lambda>
    r = integrate.ode(lambda t, X, *args: dfunc(X,t,*args))
TypeError: dfunc() takes exactly 7 arguments (2 given)`.  I expected this to be taken care of in `set_f_params`, but it's clearly not.

Comment: Interesting error. I see this as well, `set_f_params` seems to be ignored entirely. But there's an easy mitigation, see my edit.